# Unable to use ssh to connect to visual studio online git repo

Tags: git, ssh, azure-devops

I created a key pair using

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "me@my.com"
```

This created id_rsa and id_rsa.pub. I copied these into my home directory under a subdirectory .ssh. To my understanding this registers the private key and allows applications like git to use them. I then when to my visual studio online project and Added an SSH public key using the contents of id_rsa.pub. This created a Fingerprint. To my understanding this allows clients with this ssh token to access my Git repository.

Next I wanted to use this to clone my repository

```
$ git clone https://xyz.visualstudio.com/_git/myCode
Cloning into 'myCode'...
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://xyz.visualstudio.com/_git/myCode/'
```

What do I need to do to make the git clone command use my ssh keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use SSH endpoint: click Clone in web page > Select SSH tab

[image]

More information, you can refer to this article: [Use SSH key authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using https as protocol you can not enjoy the SSH advantages.

I don't know visualstudio at all, but you surely needs to change the repository's remote url from `https://xyz.visualstudio.com/_git/myCode/` to something like `user@xyz.visualstudio.com:/_git/myCode/`

You obviously needs that the server accept your identity and needs to setup your public key somewhere in visualstudio.com (again, don't use this software, so don't know where / how)